# A ton of errors in panels content editor

Tags: panels, theming

There's a whole slew of errors at the top of my panels varient content editor page and I have no clue where to start in even fixing them.  Most of these errors have been here since I started working and I have no clue how they got there or how to fix them.  I've had this exact problem on more than one site.

Also, my content got messed up and it won't let me change settings or anything. It stopped letting me change things after I added the Responsive Navigation modules block.

The theme I'm using is aurora and all it's suggested modules:

- Magic
- HTML5 Tools
- jquery update
- modernizr
- blockify
- borealis suite
- fences
- panels

The site is built on top of the Bear Distro.

Attached is a picture of what I'm looking at.
[image]

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't help at all. You need a stack trace before anyone can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known [CTools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) bug - see https://drupal.org/node/1991496 and https://drupal.org/node/1925018

Fixed in http://drupalcode.org/project/ctools.git/commitdiff/280ccd0 and the fix is available without patching if you use 7.x-1.x-dev.

Comment: This worked, however when I fixed it I lost my ability to create HTML5 layouts.  That's something for people who use Aurora to keep in mind.